# Updating composer after adding a dependency in Laravel 4 gives me error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I get the following error on a fresh Laravel 4 install after adding a new dependency to the `composer.json` and running `composer update`. Any ideas?

```
[RuntimeException]
Source directory /var/www/projects/adcraft/vendor/laravel/framework has uncommitted changes.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go in that vendor/laravel/framework directory and run `git status`  to see what changes there are. Anyway if you `self-update` composer to its latest version, it should now prompt you and ask if you want to revert those changes before updating instead of failing hard.

Comment: That solved it, thanks! It turned out all those modifications were the result of a misapplied `chmod`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way you can solve this is by setting the discard changes in the config parameter in your composer.json file, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#discard-changes.

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "description": "Demonstrating concepts",
...
  "config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800,
    "discard-changes" : true
  },
...
}
```

This worked for me.